# What other options are there to control a browser with python that aren't selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, browser-automation

Ive been working alot with browser automation and python lately, and I've been using selenium and chromedriver but I have found a few limitations. For example, it's very easy for websites to tell that you are using selenium aswell as each chrome instance taking up alot of computer memory while running. I was wondering if there are any alternative python libraries that can also control a browser window in the same ways that selenium does?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is `Pylenium` that I'm aware of. Its based on top of selenium but exposes some cypress styled DSLs. You can check out the documentation over here :

https://elsnoman.gitbook.io/pylenium/